# Int& to const int -static vs dynamic-

Tags: c++, dynamic, reference, constants

```
class A
{ 
public:
  A(int i = 25) {x = i;y=new int[i];for(int j=0;j<i;j++) y[j]=j;}
  int& f() const {return x;}
  int& operator[](int i) const {return y[i];}

private:
  int x,*y;
};

int main()
{ 
   A a(15); 
   cout << a[5];
   cout << a.f();

   return 0;
}
```

When I'm trying to compile the code it says

```
"Invalid initialization of reference of type int& from expression of type const int"
```

regarding f() function.

I understand it,since it returns a non-const reference to something declared as const by the function. But shouldn't it behave the same with the [] overloading?

It also returns a non-const reference to something that the function declared as const,but it shows no error there.
What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is telling you that you can't return a non-const lvalue reference to a data member from a `const` member function. You need

```
const int& f() const {return x;}
```

You may decide to provide a non-const overload if needed:

```
int& f() {return x;}
```

As for `operator[]`, it does not return a reference to a data member. You cannot modify `x` or `y` via `operator[]`, so it is really a `const` member function. You may decide to disallow modification to the data *pointed at* by `y`, and this would make sense if your class models an array. But it isn't strictly necessary and the compiler has no reason to enforce it.

```
const int& operator[](int i) const {return y[i];}
int& operator[](int i) {return y[i];}
```

Comment: Yes,I understood that. But shouldn't it say the same for the [] overloading function?

Comment: @flaviumanica That isn't returning a reference to a data member.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here:

```
int& f() const {return x;}
```

Your function is marked `const`, so it can be only invoked by `const` instances. However, you return a non-`const` reference, therefore if valid you can use it an modify `const` instances. The compiler is not happy with this. Hence `f()` should return `const int&` instead.

On the other hand, `int& operator[](int) const` compiles, since you return a reference to the data the pointer member `y` points to, but you cannot modify the pointer itself. In other words, on a `const` instance, the pointer `y` is `const`, i.e. `int * const y`, but not the data. Therefore bitwise `const`-ness is preserved, but of course logical `const`-ness is not, however the compiler only cares about bit-wise `const`-ness.

To enforce logical `const` correctness, one option is to write 2 versions of your `operator[]`:

```
const int& operator[](int i) const {return y[i];}
```

and

```
int& operator[](int i) {return y[i];}
```

Note that the second version should be marked non-`const`, as otherwise you'd try to overload two functions that differ only by their return type. If you want to avoid code duplication in the non-`const` version, you can make use of the `const` version via a `const_cast`, like

```
int& operator[](int i) 
{
    return const_cast<int&>(const_cast<const A&>(*this)[i]); // use the const version
}
```

**EDIT**

There is a proposal to introduce a `const`-propagating wrapper for pointer-like data members, `propagate_const`, which in effect will also make the data pointed to `const`, see

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4057.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In C++ language constness of a class implies immediate constness of all its members (except for `mutable` ones). However, constness of the class does not propagate to data *pointed by pointer members* or *referenced by reference members*. That pointed/referenced data is not part of the class and its constness is not affected by constness of the class.

In your example, declaring a member function as `const` makes it treat members `x` and `y` as `const`. However, the data pointed by `y` does not become `const`, e.g. neither `*y` nor `y[i]` are `const`.

Propagation of constness from the enclosing class to the pointed/referenced data is actually a part of user intent. It is something you need or don't need depending on what you are trying to implement. The language leaves it completely up to you (or to a library-level solution).